# How to make an API request In React on button click

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to build a random quote generator that loads A quote on componentDidMount with an axios api request , then loads new quotes on button click.

This is for A freecodecamp project. I have tried making the call again on button click, then adding the new response to state, but it will not work at all.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Button from './Button';
    import axios from 'axios'
    class QuoteBox extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          quotes: []

        }

     }
    componentDidMount(){
     axios.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts? 
    filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1')
     .then(res=> this.setState({quotes: res.data[0]}))

    }
    getNext = (ev) =>{
      ev.preventDefault()
      axios.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts? 
    filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=2')
      .then(res=> this.setState({quotes:[...this.state,res.data[0]]}))
    }


    render(){
    const {content,title} = this.state.quotes
    const filteredContent = String(content).replace(/(<\w>)|(<\/\w>)| 
    (&#\d{4})/gm, "").replace(/(;)/g,"'")
     console.log(content)

     return(
       <React.Fragment>
          <h2>A little inspiration for the day</h2>
          <div className='outerQuoteBox'>
            <div className='innerQuoteBox'>
                <p>{filteredContent}</p><br/><br/>{title}
            </div>
            <Button getNext={this.getNext} />
        </div>
        </React.Fragment>)
       }
      }
    export default QuoteBox
```

And this is my button component

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'

   export class Button extends Component {
    render() {
     return (
      <React.Fragment>
       <button onClick={this.props.getNext} className='nextBtn' 
         type='button'>Next</button>
       </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
   }

   export default Button
```

When I click the button, it seems like the request isn't going through at all. If i check State in the dev tools, only the first quote from componentDidMount is in the array. I don't understand where my mistake is.

Edit: I had used the wrong prop reference, so it wasn't making the call. I fixed this and it does make the call now, and it brings in one new quote, but that's it. And it doesn't add the new one to state, it just replaces it with the one new one. and that's all it will do. The `api` instructions say the end point i'm using should return a new random quote, but it does not.

Comment: You don't need a React.Fragment around button it's a single element

Comment: Thank you, I had multiple buttons at first, and changed it and forgot to remove the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're referencing the wrong prop on the button.

Change `getQuote` to `getNext` and it should work...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Button extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={this.props.getNext} className='nextBtn' 
      type='button'>Next</button>
    </React.Fragment>
   )
 }
}

export default Button
```

Comment: Oops, Thats a big face Palm. You are right about it making the call now, but it will only bring in one new quote, and is not saving the first one to state. Do you know what may be causing this?